# "detail": "Method \"GET\" not allowed." Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, http-post

I know this question maybe a duplicate, but I have tried many solutions and could not understand any. I have followed this tutorial exactly and yet I get this error on the 'userlist' page. Everything else works just fine. Can somebody point out what the error is ?

```
class UserList(APIView):
"""
Create a new user. It's called 'UserList' because normally we'd have a get
method here too, for retrieving a list of all User objects.
"""

permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
http_method_names = ['get', 'head']

def post (self, request, format=None):
    self.http_method_names.append("GET")

    serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

EDIT:
urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from classroom.views.classroom import current_user, UserList
from .views import classroom, suppliers, teachers
urlpatterns = [path('', classroom.home, name='home'),
               path('current_user/', current_user),
               path('users/', UserList.as_view()),
```

Edit:

Still getting this error,

[image: err]

Comment: Share your ```urls.py``` and the endpoint url you are trying?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add GET endpoint url to your `urls.py` in order to use GET requests. GET url is missing in your `urls.py`, simply edit your `urls.py` like:

```py
# urls.py

from django.urls import include, path
from classroom.views.classroom import current_user, UserList
from .views import classroom, suppliers, teachers

urlpatterns = [
               path('', classroom.home, name='home'),
               path('current_user/', current_user),
               path('users/', UserList.as_view()),
               path('users/<int:pk>/', UserList.as_view()),
              ]
```

And you need to implement `get` method in your`UserList` view such as:

```py
# views.py

class UserList(APIView):
    """
    Create a new user. It's called 'UserList' because normally we'd have a get
    method here too, for retrieving a list of all User objects.
    """

    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head']


    def get(self, request, format=None):
        users = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(users, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        self.http_method_names.append("GET")

        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: But you never changed the function `UserList` to accept `pk` ?? How can this work ?

Comment: Oh, I did not realize that. But, I am still getting that error. I do not understand by reading the tutorial I am following, what exaclty is the purpose of this 'users' page ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you maybe explain a little what was going wrong ?

Comment: To allow using ```GET``` requests, you simply need to implement ```get``` method in ```APIView```. When asking your question, you had only implemented ```post``` method, that's why you couldn't use ```GET``` method. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/ is a good document to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the problem is that, there is not functionality defined for `GET` requests in your view. So either you can add it, like this:

```
class UserList(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['get', 'head', 'post']

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(User.objects.all(), many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

    def post (self, request, format=None):
        self.http_method_names.append("GET")
        serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Or you can subclass `UserList` View from [`ListAPIView`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview).

**FYI**, `permission_classes` won't work with `APIView`. You need to use [**`GenericAPIView`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) or any other generic views to have those functionalities.

Comment: I get an error at this line `serializer = UserSerializerWithToken(queryset=User.objects.all(), many=True) ` . Error is  `TypeError at /users/`

Comment: `TypeError at /users/
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/
Django Version: 2.0.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'queryset'
Exception Location: C:\Users\idadarklord\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py in __init__, line 117`

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake in code. Updated my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but I noticed that in my views.py, I had

```
renderer_class = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

I corrected it to :

```
renderer_classes = api_settings.DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES
```

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are calling 'post' from where ever you are calling, example as 'postman'

but your function is

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

so call as 'get' or change your function to

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```

Comment: This is already mentioned in the other answers.